# Why doesn't insert the insert execute?

Tags: javascript, sql, firefox-addon

The database has opened, and the table has created. But I can't Insert record, I'm useing mozilla sqlite storage:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");
let file = FileUtils.getFile("ProfD", ["filef.sqlite"]);
let dbconn = Services.storage.openDatabase(file);
dbconn.executeSimpleSQL('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "quicklink" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL , "name" VARCHAR NOT NULL , "href" VARCHAR NOT NULL )');
var sqlinsert=dbconn.createStatement('INSERT INTO "quicklink" ("name","href") VALUES (:name,:href)');
sqlinsert.params.name = "Something";
sqlinsert.params.href = "URL";
dbconn.close();
```

I don't get any error(s) in firebug console, or whit the try{}catch(){} statement. Why? What is the problem whit it?

Comment: Don't know what syntax that is but where is the `execute` part of this code?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Are there any errors? Does it silently fail?

Comment: doesn't work mean it doesn't add the record to the table

Comment: You have the full context of your problem, we don't .. and you haven't conveyed it in your question. Take a few deep breaths and edit it, then flag it for moderator attention once you have to be reviewed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In general, you CANNOT do database access from client-side Javascript.

   There are many exceptions (for example, maybe you're using Node.js on a server, or maybe you're using HP WebOS on a local Sqlite database), but I didn't see anything in your post about your environment or database connectivity.
2. Assuming you CAN legitimately connect to a database with Javascript in your environment, I don't see where you're executing the prepared SQL statement.

Suggestions:

1. Please specify the database and database library you're using
2. Please show us the "execute" statement and corresponding error handler
3. Please cut/paste any error messages you're getting in the error handler or in the database log.

ADDENDUM:

OK - I'm with you now:

1) You're using the Mozilla "Storage" API.

2) You need to call "executeStatement()" after your "createStatement()".

3) You should also have a "handleError" function.

The documentation and sample code is here:

http://developer.mozilla.org/En/Storage

Comment: Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
 Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");
  
 let file = FileUtils.getFile("ProfD", ["filef.sqlite"]);
 let dbconn = Services.storage.openDatabase(file);
 dbconn.executeSimpleSQL('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "quicklink" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL , "name" VARCHAR NOT NULL , "href" VARCHAR NOT NULL )');
 var sqlinsert=dbconn.createStatement('INSERT INTO "quicklink" ("name","href") VALUES (:name,:href)');
 sqlinsert.params.name = "Something";
 sqlinsert.params.href = "URL";

Comment: dbconn.close();

This is in Firefox add-on... And the create table work!

Comment: In the first one you are executing the statement --> `executeSimpleSQL` in the second one you are not

Comment: if I change createStatement to executeSimpleSQL it doesn't hapen anything, maybe it has something error, because the innerhtml doesn't work later... how can I get error message?

Comment: this works dbconn.executeSimpleSQL('INSERT INTO "quicklink" ("nev","href") VALUES ("Something","URL")'); but how can I use params in this?

Comment: remove your last 3 sentences shown here and replace with this one: dbconn.executeSimpleSQL('INSERT INTO "quicklink" ("name","href") VALUES ("Something", "URL")'); // try other quotes if this are not valid or find the .executeStatment method (or similar) in that library as many says here

Comment: OK - I'm with you now.  1) You're using the Mozilla "Storage" API.  2) You need to call "executeStatement()" after your "createStatement()".  3) You should also have a "handleError" function.  The documentation and sample code is here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Storage

Comment: yes it's correct, missing the sqlinsert.executeStatement(); line, and also, I don't need to quotation marks, var sqlinsert=dbconn.createStatement('INSERT INTO quicklink (name,href) VALUES (:name,:href)');

Answer (score 0):

What database server are you using?  If you're using SQL Server, use the profiler to see what command actually gets executed against SQL Server and see what the errors are that it generates.